# Selenium Grid with safari browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

Plese Help me
How do I instantiate the Safari in selenium grid

```
    capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            // Version browser
            capabilities.setVersion(versaoBrowser);
            capabilities.setBrowserName("safari");
            capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
            // Platform test runner
            capabilities.setPlatform(platform);
```

On the server is weel

```
-browser "browserName=safari,version=5,platform=WINDOWS,javascriptEnable=true"
```

Comment: Which version of Selenium are you using?  The Safari browser is not working correctly according to [the last comment by user Darrell here](http://darrellgrainger.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/using-selenium-20-with-webdriver-and.html?showComment=1333108018252#c9157838719535505020)

Answer (score 1):

If the question is about using Safari the new way, with SafariDriver over Grid2, then this would be the typical method I believe (more or less):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.*;
import java.net.*;

DesiredCapabilities c = new DesiredCapabilities();
c.setBrowserName("safari");
/* you can then set version & platform as well, but the minimum is just browser. Maybe for Grid2 you need the others, but for remote web driver only, you don't.
*/

WebDriver d = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://hubIpOrHostname:hubPort/wd/hub"),c);
```

and that should work. On the server side, I believe you just instantiate normally for Grid2 per the wiki docs (last I check, could be diff now):

//start hub
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar -role hub -port theHubPort

//start the node
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar -role node -hub http:
//172.22.6.198:4446/wd/hub -port theNodePort

however, seems that the current Grid2 doesn't offer Safari support. When I looked up the console for the registered node in hub, it didn't show icon for Safari. Maybe I missed something. I'll try adding platform and version next time to see if that makes a diff but think not.

Here's a snippet of the error I get for Grid2 with SafariDriver:

May 11, 2012 6:01:11 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver execute
INFO: Executing: [null, newSession {"desiredCapabilities":"Capabilities [{browse
rName=safari}]"}]
// Error: // Uncaught Exception: Typed variable declaration : Object constructor
 : at Line: 7 : in file:  : new RemoteWebDriver ( new URL ( "http:
//172.22.6.198:4446/wd/hub" ) , c )

Target exception: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the n
ew session cannot find : {browserName=safari}
Command duration or timeout: 109 milliseconds

**To note:** with webdriver, same code can be used for (standalone) remote webdriver execution vs grid, difference is that for remote you use remote server ip and with grid2, you use hub ip. SafariDriver works over remote webdriver, but currently doesn't seem to work over Grid2 yet.

remote webdriver startup:

java -jar selenum-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar [-port somePort]
//default port of 4444

Comment: While the grid console doesn't show the icon, that doesn't mean it won't properly proxy a Safari request.  The grid hub is simply a load balancing router for requested capabilities to registered provided capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are asking for is something like this?

```
selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, *safari,"http://google.com.au");
selenium.start();
```

I generally use WebDriver, but my understanding is capabilities are options for when you create an instance of a browser, not to open the browser itself. Though I could be wrong as I am not experienced with Selenium Grid.

EDIT: [This](http://darrellgrainger.blogspot.com.au/2011/02/using-selenium-20-with-webdriver-and.html) and [this](http://qtp-help.blogspot.com.au/2011/08/selenium-grid-for-browser-compatibility.html) might help.

Comment: So I'm using selenium web driver, this type of instance is the selenium RC, got to have progress on this, my library updated for selenium 2.21 and now my code is well <code>
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.safari();

capabilities.setBrowserName("safari");
capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
capabilities.setPlatform(platform); </code> and am having a new problem with the location of the safari...<br>  
Please add the directory containing ''Safari.exe'' to your PATH environment
variable, or explicitly specify a path to Safari like this:
*safari c:\blah\Safari.exe

Comment: This is because you must place your Safari Driver either in a location you will call in your code (eg. safari = new safariDriver("WHERE IT IS");) or add the file path to your PATH environment. If you need help with this process please let me know and I'll take screenshots and a-like to explain.

Comment: JoaoSakai, can you post the exact error details you get? I think that may be helpful to the rest of us. I don't recall seeing that error myself. I thought you can only specify path to Firefox, not IE and Safari...this is news to me.

Comment: Also, I could be wrong but I believe DesiredCapabilities.safari() is a new feature for WebDriver/Selenium in trunk. Meanwhile the Java bindings for SafariDriver and the standalone server JAR are at release 2.21, which doesn't have that option. So you should use the old way of using a generic DesiredCapabilities object then set the browser name, version, and platform.

Comment: I am currently specifying a path to my InternetExplorerDriver.exe when creating a new IE driver instance. In fact, the only browser where I don't have to do this is Firefox as it uses the IDE instead of a driver.exe to run the browser (or at least this is the impression I got). Though, I have not used Safari before and perhaps I am missing something here?